# Request and response to other server in same page using RequestHeader

Tags: curl, vbscript, asp-classic, output

How can I show the output from other server in vbscript/ASP after I make a request for value A and B.

The situation:

- my page request to other server value for A and B..
- the server response value for A and B..
- i want publish the output in same page, value from server for A and B.

Here is my code:

```
<% 
'URL to open....<br> 
sUrl = "some url" 
'POST Request to send. 
a="aaa" 
b="111" 
sRequest = "value1=a&value2=b" 
HTTPPost sUrl, sRequest 

Function HTTPPost(sUrl, sRequest) 
    Set oHTTP=Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")     
    oHTTP.setOption 2, 13056 
    oHTTP.open "POST", sUrl,false 
    oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
    oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sRequest) 
    oHTTP.send sRequest 
    HTTPPost = oHTTP.responseText 
End Function 
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no string interpolation in VBScript, so you need to concatenate to build the parameter string:

```vb
sRequest = "value1=" & escape(a) & "&value2=" & escape(b)
```

Depending on the values of a and b, you may also need to use [`escape()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3607h29(v=vs.84).aspx) to ensure that it is HTTP friendly, which I've added above.

To show in the page, you can simply write the return value of `HTTPPost()` to the `Response` object - although this of course will need to change depending on what that value is and how you want to show it on the page.

```
Response.Write HTTPPost(sUrl, sRequest)
```